# Using the dfuse API, can I use a single EoswsClient-Instance to stream responds for multiple "getActionTraces"-requests?

Tags: dfuse

example code below:

```
client = new EoswsClient(createEoswsSocket(() => new ws(`wss://${config.dfuse.endpoint}/v1/stream?token=${config.dfuse.token}`, { origin: config.dfuse.origin })));
    await client.connect();
    client.getActionTraces({ accounts: "eoscontract1" }).onMessage(onMessage);
    client.getActionTraces({ accounts: "eoscontract2" }).onMessage(onMessage);
```

I'm getting the following Error-Message:
[image]

Does this mean that if I want to stream 2 different actions for two different accounts, I would have to instantiate two EoswsClient-instances and to establish two connections?

Here is the context that I set for the stream:

```
const undelegatebw = {
  accounts: accounts.join("|"),
  receiver: receivers.join("|"),
  //   action_names: "voteproducer,delegatebw,undelegatebw"
  action_names: "undelegatebw"
};
const voteproducer = {
  accounts: accounts.join("|"),
  receiver: receivers.join("|"),
  //   action_names: "voteproducer,delegatebw,undelegatebw"
  action_names: "voteproducer"
};
```

```
await dfuseWs.getActionTraces(undelegatebw, options, undelegatebwHandle);
await dfuseWs.getActionTraces(voteproducer, options, voteproducerHandle);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use two different req_id's if you want to receive specific actions of two contracts.

```
await dfuseWs.getActionTraces({ accounts: "eoscontract1", action_names: "undelegatebw" }, { req_id: "A" }).onMessage(...);
await dfuseWs.getActionTraces({ accounts: "eoscontract2", action_names: "voteproducer" }, { req_id: "B" }).onMessage(...);
```

If you want to receive action-traces for every action of both contracts you don't even need to send two requests.

```
await dfuseWs.getActionTraces({ account: "eoscontract1|eoscontract2"}).onMessage(...);
```

Comment: If this is the case, say if I listen to `voteproducer` and `delegatebw` separately, can dfuse guarantee that the actions that I receive on both requests is in the right timely order?

Comment: Not sure if they can "guarantee" that, you should probably ask in their channel. My personal experience is that it works very well and I personally havn't had any problems with the order of transactions for know and the behaviour/order of respopnses, if it's a normal, inline or deferred trx always seems to be predictable. Same for table-deltas.

Comment: No, two streams are not connected together and runs concurrently, ordering is guaranteed only inside a single stream. When two streams are registered, the messages can arrive in any order is you were to "fusion" the streams.